# How to translate "once" and "every" in Japanese? 一度 or いつも

Tags: adverbs, time, english-to-japanese

`[一度]{いちど(ひとたび)}` means `once`, but `[一遍]{いっぺん}` also mean `once` in sentences like `once I did something` or `once I am a something`.

`常に` means `always` in sentences like `I always am a something` or `I always do something`

But idiomatically, `Once bitten twice shy` is translated as `[羹]{あつもの}に[懲]{こ}りて[膾]{なます}を[吹]{ふ}く` in Japanese.

So if I want to say `Once a thief, always a thief`, is this phrase grammatical `盗人一度, 常に盗人`?

What if I want to say `Once a X, always a X`? and X is a noun/noun phrase?

Comment: There is also 一回 for "one time/once".

Comment: ALC has an entry for `Once a thief, always a thief`: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=once+a+thief%2c+always+a+thief

Comment: You might also opt for 泥棒 over 盗人... which apparently is read ぬすっと

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are making the mistake of attempting to replicate an English pattern in Japanese.

As snailboat points out, the idiomatic equivalent is as follows:

> 泥棒はいつまでたっても泥棒。／三つ子の魂百まで。／性格を変えることはできない。

And if you make this search,

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=Once+a+always+a

one finds that the nearest Japanese equivalent seems to be:

> noun phrase はいつまでたっても noun phrase

If one uses the vocabulary you suggested, the nearest equivalent seems to be:

> Once an actor, always an actor.
>   一度役者をやればやめられない。
>   Once an addict, always an addict.
>   一度中毒になるとやめられない。

Comment: anyone want to explain 三つ子の魂百まで? or link to an explanation?

Comment: http://kotowaza-allguide.com/mi/mitsugonotamashii.html

Comment: @snailboat, thanks. but i still don't understand it. do you?

Comment: The spirit of a three-year-old child remains the same, even when they're a hundred years old.

Comment: sorry i kept reading 三つ子 as triplets. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For "Once a X, always a X", some suggestions would be 「Xはなおらず」 or 「XはXのまま」.